# REGEXTRACT on Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the "4.148" out of cell B13, but I get an error saying the parameters don't match.

Have I done any obvius errors? I'm quite new to Google Spreadsheets.
Also that number will change in time so I can't just extract the exact value...

[Here is what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpv4R.png)

[image]

Comment: What is the entire value of the cell `B13`?

Comment: =REGEXEXTRACT(CONCATENA(IMPORTXML(G4; "//script[2]"));".*\]\]")

In cell G4 is the url of the website where I need to get the value from

Comment: `B13`, not `D13`.

Comment: I basically splitted the formula between B13 and D13 in the end it will be just B13, but I wanted to see the result of half formula to see if I could find my error. Cell B13 is =REGEXEXTRACT(CONCATENA(IMPORTXML(G4; "//script[2]"));".*]]") . And cell D13 is =REGEXEXTRACT(B13; "[0–9]+\."), theoretically in the end it should be =REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(CONCATENATE(IMPORTXML(G4, “//script[2]”)),”.*\]\]”), “[0–9]+\.[0–9]+”)
I hope I was clear enough, feel free to ask more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, " \+0"",(.+),""")
```

[image: 0]